# Mostrar uma DIV e ocultar outra se o parâmetro na url for um parâmetro predefinido

Tags: php, html, div, tabela-html

Não sei se a pergunta foi formulada corretamente mas enfim... Meu problema é o seguinte:

O usuário vai digitar um código tal e ira clicar em buscar. Essa solicitação ira passar por um PHP que ira checar se esse código esta presente no arquivo code.txt e abrir uma pagina com uma tabela contendo dados referentes ao código ou então abrir uma pagina de erro caso o código esteja incorreto:

```
$track = $_POST['code'];
$codigo = file_get_contents("codes.txt");
$codigo = explode(PHP_EOL, $codigo); // PHP_EOL is for a line break
if(in_array($track, $codigo)){
header("LOCATION: pages/track.html?code=$track");
} else {
header("LOCATION: pages/error.html");
}
```

Meu problema e que eu queria que o url ficasse sempre assim: meusite.com/pages/track.html?code=$track

Apenas mudando o parâmetro ($track), se não eu teria que criar uma pagina para cada código. E a cada código/parâmetro diferente mostrasse uma DIV contendo uma tabela e ocultasse as outras.

Exemplo:

O usuário foi na pagina inicial digitou o código correto (123456789) la na caixa de busca e foi para pagina meusite.com/pages/track.html?code=123456789 mostrando numa tabela os dados referentes aquele código e na mesma pagina ele digitou outro código correto (111222333) e foi mudado apenas o parâmetro da url, ficando assim: meusite.com/pages/track.html?code=111222333. E junto com o novo parâmetro foi ocultada a outra tabela e mostrada a nova tabela que contem os dados referentes a esse novo código. Enfim, eu queria apenas que fosse mudado o conteúdo da pagina mas que fosse preservado o modelo de url: meusite.com/pages/track.html?code=$track... Agradeco a quem leu ate aqui e desculpe pela falta de acentuação, e que meu teclado esta com problemas.

Comment: Eu entendi o que você quis dizer. É meio comprido e chato pra te explicar sem o visual (passo-a-passo) agora mas tenho o video de professor meu que te mostra isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8lc7LUonQU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso terias de mudar a tua requisição de `$_POST` para `$_REQUEST`, que captura, tanto os valores enviandos via *POST*, como os enviados via *GET*, desde que possuam a palavra `code` como índice.

De qualquer das formas isto não vai funcionar, pelo simples facto de a página em uso ser `.html`, o que te impede de usar *PHP* nela, à menos que estejas a usar *Ajax* ou algo parecido vais continuar a ter este problema.